# Database structure for house facilities

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a new project. I really just started it and I am orientating myself on how I want to build the structure of the pages and of course the database.

The page will be about houses/ appartments and so on that you can rent (for like a week with family or a weekend with your friends).

The user can register, and add a `house` (it may be extended with the ability to add more houses).
So I came up with this base DB structure:

```
table users
-----------
user_id
user_email
user_password


table house
-----------
house_id
user_id
house_name
...
house_num_bedrooms
house_description
```

As you can see the table house has some attributes that all the houses have, like number of bedrooms, minimum and maximum number of people that can stay, and so on. Those 'fix attributes' are assigned in the table `house`.

Now the user must be able to select facilities, a part of the list:

```
Category: kitchen
- Microwave       [yes|no]
- Coffee machine  [senseo|2 pot|3 pot]
- Water boiler    [yes|no]
- Refrigerator    [yes|no]

Category: bedrooms
- number of bedrooms           [xx]
- number of 1-person-beds      [xx]
- number of 2-person-beds      [xx]
- number of 2-person boxspring [xx]
```

Behind the facilities are possibilities listed, so some facilities are either there or not, others is the number of the facilities (for examples, 26 bedrooms with 20 1-person-beds and 6 2-person-beds).

At the beginning I will already have a nice list of facilities (approx. 100).

The question is, what is the best way of saving this in a db, with a flexible database, or a table called facilities with all the facilities as columns?

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to facilities: you need one table in which are stored all the facilities - id and name (possibly along with a text field which contains extra information regarding that facility, like 2 euro/day) - and a join table, which joins houses and facilities. This table could also contain a 'number' field and a 'cost' field, although the latter is problematic as some facilities cost on a per day basis, like city tax, and some are on a per stay basis, like final cleaning. This is left as an exercise.

As it happens, I was just looking at apartments to rent in Florence, so I can easily give you an example.

```
APARTMENTS
id
daily price
name
address

FACILITIES
id
name
extra details

FACBYAPART // join table, find your own name
apartment
facility
quantity
cost
```

example data:

Apartments - 1, 82, Green Fig; 2, 95, Belfiore 2

Facilities - 1, Final cleaning; 2, Wifi; 3, single bed; 4, double bed

FacByApart - 1,1,1,40; 1,2,1,0; 1,3,1,0; 1,4,1,0; 2,1,1,0; 2,2,1,2; 2,3,2,0; 2,4,2,0.

The data shows that the Green Fig apartment has final cleaning (at a cost of 40 Euro), free wifi, one single bed and one double bed. Belfiore 2 has free final cleaning, wifi costs 2 euro, two single beds and 2 double beds.

This is the standard way of defining a database such as you need. Later on, you'll need a calendar table, which would have a date, an apartment, a price for that apartment on that date and the name of the person who has booked the apartment for that date (no value means that the apartment is free). Then you'll need a table for people who have booked ....

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for the schema design along use case for your requirements:

```
APARTMENT
id:1;2
name:Valley View;City Center
address: Narayan Rd 50;Kanti Rd 30
daily price: 40;60

FACILITy
id:1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
name:Double Bed;Kitchen Set;Double Bed BoxSpring;Car;Movie Theater;Refrigenator;Water boiler;Final Cleaning
remarks:;All kitchenware(refrigenerator, water boiler,cofee machine, microwave) Available;;;;;;;

APARTMENT_FACILITy
id:1;2;3;4;5;6;7
apartment_id:1;1;1;1;2;2;2
facility_id:1;2;4;5;1;6;7
quantity:2;1;1;1;1;1;1
cost:0;0;20;50;0;0;0
cost_frequency_days:0;0;1;7;0;0;0

APARTMENT_USER
id:1;2
email:abc@abc.com;xyz@abc.com
password;secret1_hash;secret2_hash

RENTAL_DETAILs
id:1;2;3;4
apartment_id;1
arrival_date:2015-01-10
departure_date:2015-01-13
apartment_user_id:1
```

**Considerations:**

```
Referred Apartment for both house and apartment. Users table holds email for username and password for the credentials, you can extend other fields as per your requirements. Add additional fields in other tables as per your requirements.

case #1-You have Valley View apartment at Naryanan Rd 50 and cost per day is $80, it offers 2 Double Beds and Kitchen. Additional Cost: Car - $20/day and Movie Theater $50/Week

case #2-You have City Center apartment at Kanti Rd 30 and cost per day is $30, it offers 1 Double Bed, Refrigenator and Water boiler.

Case #3-User abc@abc.com stay in Valley View Apartment for 4 days(2015-01-10 to 2015-01-13)=>40+80(Car-20X4days)+50(one week charge).
```